Issue with Anova, Effects, and Multiple comparisons in JMP
I am trying to run an Anova on a data set I have from our lab. Briefly, we exposed some particles at 3 different sizes to some cells at 2 different doses and measured gene expression. 
The issue I am running into is that when I go to perform my Anova it keeps giving me an error for my Dose and won't give me a P-value for it. As a result I cannot run a Tukeys-HSD post-hoc for my multiple comparisons and look at particle*dose interactions. 
I have my Gene Expression as Numeric/Continuous, Particle Size as Character/Nominal, and my Dose as Numeric/Continuous. For Model Dialog I have my Gene Expression as my Y variable and Particle Size, Dose, and Particle Size*Dose as my model effects. 
Based on these parameters I get the following output (see screenshots). I have tried several variations of this setup and even attempted to solve the problem using R and myself/others get the same results.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks
As previously mentioned myself/others have tried multiple variations to get this to work from using R (in case artefact of JMP) and got similar results. We have also tried changing the data/modeling type from Numeric to Character and vice-versa.
